# REGEX - negative lookahead multiline check

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, regex-negation

I need help with regular expression to find all `<lightning:input/>` fields in component that doesn't contain "maxlength" attribute.

Example of input:

```
   <lightning:input value="{!v.value}" 
                    aura:id="field" name="name" 
                    maxlength="50" 
                    label="label" 
                    required="true" 
                    />
```

I've already tried this `(<lightning:input)(?!.*(maxlength))` but it only checks the first line of input (no new lines included). I need to use it in IntelliJ IDEA search.

Comment: Most probably `<lightning:input(?![^<]*?maxlength=)` will be enough.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.*` construct used in the lookahead only lets you check for the subsequent subpatterns on one line. However, you may not use `(?s)` DOTALL modifier here to allow `.` to match across lines because `*` is greedy and will go as far as possible in the document and might match a `maxlength` substring in another node text.

Thus, the safest regex way is to use a `[^<]*?` construct that matches any 0+ chars other than `<` (including line break chars) as few as possible:

```
<lightning:input(?![^<]*?maxlength=)
```

Note I added `=` to make sure the `maxlength` substring is followed with `=`. To match `maxlength` as  a whole word, add `\b` (word boundary) or even `\s` (whitespace) before it.